# Drag and Drop between trees and within one of the trees

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have two trees in Extjs 4.1 with the drag and drop plugin enabled.  The user can drag and drop between these trees.  Here is the only relevant configurations for these trees in this situation is the viewConfig:

tree 1:

```
viewConfig:{
            plugins: [
                new PmProjectManagement.viewEdit.AvailableCriteriaTreeViewDragDrop({
                    allowContainerDrop: true,
                    allowParentInsert: false,
                    expandDelay: 30000,
                    dropGroup: "secondGridDDGroup",
                    dragGroup: "firstGridDDGroup"
                })
            ]
        }
```

tree 2:

```
viewConfig:{
            plugins: [
                new PmProjectManagement.viewEdit.ViewConfigTreeViewDragDrop({
                    allowContainerDrop: true,
                    allowParentInsert: false,
                    expandDelay: 30000,
                    dropGroup: "firstGridDDGroup",
                    dragGroup: "secondGridDDGroup"
                })
            ]
        }
```

Right now I can drag and drop from one tree to another just fine, but what I really want is to be able to drag from tree 1 to tree 2, from tree 2 to tree 1, AND within tree 2.  I am having trouble with the draggin around in tree 2 because the ddGroup is set to the other tree.  I also need tree 1 to not be able to drag around within it.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to go about this?  The only solution I can think of involves using overrides on the isValidDropPoint function and removing the ddGroup qualifiers, but I would really like a more elegant approach to this.

Comment: yay....  got the tumbleweed badge for this.  Kinda surprised no one has any idea how to do this.

Comment: I figured out a very complicated solution to this.  I'm not going to post it unless there is some actual interest though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ddGroup` should be the same for both trees.

In ext 4.2 you have the `nodedragover` event notifying the Ext.tree.View during dragging.
This event is going from the `Ext.tree.ViewDropZone#isValidDropPoint`.

So in the ext 4.2 you just need to processing this event and decide drop is allowed or not, event firing gives you a lot of information, so you can found out that is dragging and which tree is used [the event description](http://ext-4.2.0.sencha/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.tree.View-event-nodedragover).

`dragData` parameter contains "view" property from which you can take the tree - drop destination tree, like `dragData.view.panel`.

In ext 4.1 you are right there was no the view notifications, guys from sencha even placed a todo marker that this must be implemented in the new version. And yes you can extend the `Ext.tree.ViewDropZone` and firing kind of event to notify the view about the dragging over (something similar to 4.2). Also you need to extend the `Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop` plugin to inject there your's just extended `Ext.tree.ViewDropZone`. 
It is just overriding `onViewRender` method of the plugin and use your's just extended drop zone.

Then use new plugin. Another way just override the `Ext.tree.ViewDropZone` to be applied everywhere in the application.

IMHO you do no need change the dd groups, all you need is just processing the `nodedragover` in 4.2 of some kinda of implementation.

Comment: You look correct.  I did it back then very similarly to the way to described for 4.1, I was just hoping for a simpler solution back then.

Comment: Yes, I've played a lot with this. The nightmare then you need dragging and dropping from the tree to grid upon any node for instance. But grid shows the listing of nodes from tree and listing is showen on selectionchage of tree (cause a keys default implementation in the tree left, right change selection in it and etc.). Selection model of the tree change the selection on mouse down, this is not right because we want to drag for instance a node to the tree not show its listing (like simple file browser works) and here a lot of palys and changing insight )